# Filtering numbers from a django list

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

In my database I have a list of users, each one has an id, this id is CharField, it can contain either a string containing a number (e.g "058") or a string containing something like this "0Y5"

The id field, is not primary key

I want to filter the list of users to have only the ones that have an id that contain a valid number, like "005", "011", "122",

I tried this but it seems not working:

```
 users = User.objects.filter(id.isnumeric == True)
```

Comment: Have a look at [The pk lookup shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#the-pk-lookup-shortcut)

Comment: I misunderstood your question, and have edited my answer below.  It should be `users = User.objects.filter(id__regex=r'^[0-9]*$')`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression ([regex](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#regex)) in your query to find strings with numbers:

```py
users = User.objects.filter(id__regex=r'^[0-9]*$')
```

The `'^[0-9]*$'` will match only numbers from the beginning (`^`) of the string to the end (`$`) where the numbers `[0-9]` can be repeated (`*`).  The `r` means that what is between the quotes is to be interpreted as a [raw string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals), so the `\` will be not be considered an escape character.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it works, I don't know if it is the best but it works!:

```
users = User.objects.all()
ids = [user.id for user in users if user.id.isnumeric()]
```